# Importing modul with async condition and accessing its service

Tags: angular, initialization, ivy

in my application i need to have two types of authentication and which one to use is determinated with async api call. Problem is that one of authentication modules has http interceptor that in not configurable and make problems so i am trying to load its modul only if this type of authentication is going to be used.

Currently i am trying something like this in InitializationFactory but i dont know how to get service from that module and i have no idea if this is correct approach. Its more or less temporary solution but both authentication types has to work at the same time for some period of time.

```
return () => {
    return featureService.getFeatures().pipe(
      concatMap((features) => {
        if (!FeatureIsOn)) {
          return EMPTY;
        }
        return from(import("/folder with module")).pipe(
          concatMap(({ Module, Service}) => {
            // Trying to inject module to imports
            const createdInjector = createInjector(Module, injector, [
              { provide: "config", useValue: config},
            ]);
            // Trying to get service
            const authService = createdInjector.get(Service);

            return authService.initAuth().pipe(
```

Any tips are welcomed. Thanks